# POST multi-part/form-data with file for TestCafe t.request

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to recreate a `curl` command in TestCafe using `t.request()`. I cannot figure out how to upload files as part of a multi-part PUT/POST request.

This is the basic curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url '<url>' \
  --header 'X-Risk-Token: <token>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form 'someField=@/path/to/file.png'
```

I can not figure out the syntax, or if this is even supported, through TestCafe `t.request()`

I tried:

```
t.request.post({ url: url, headers: headers, params: { someField: "@/path/to/file.png" } })
```

But this got a 500 error from the server, whereas it works with curl.

EDIT:
Basic testcafe example (not working):

```
const filepath = "/Users/codambro/file.png";
const url = "https://www.postman-echo.com/post";

/**
 * curl command (returns 200):
 * curl -X POST -F image=@/Users/codambro/file.png -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --url 'https://www.postman-echo.com/post'
 */

fixture("Request Test");

test("Request Test", async t => {
    const resp = await t.request.post({
        url: url,
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
        params: { "image": `@${filepath}` },
    });
    // Returning 500
    console.log(resp.status);
    console.log(resp.body);
});
```

Comment: Could you please share a simple example that can be run locally? If you don't want to share it here, you can do this in [the team repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml).

Comment: @Aleksey provided example above

Comment: Sending files using the `t.request` method is currently unsupported. We'll research this usage scenario.